# Python Datetime strptime always to precision of millisecond

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert strings e.g. "2010-01-01 10:09:01" into datetime to the precision of milliseconds. However even after adding 0 milliseconds at the back of the string e.g. "2010-01-01 10:09:01.000", the datetime always truncates the milliseconds part off. How do I make sure the datetime is always to the precision of millisecond even if there are 0 milliseconds in the timestamp? Thanks! :)
[truncating the millisecond off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0naMJ.png)

Comment: Hi, I see you are a new contributor. There are some general guidelines you should adhere to for your question to have the highest chance to be answered, e.g., not posting your code as an image but using the code formatting. You can see these guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The string `%f` you are using is returning [microseconds, not milliseconds](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). The expression returned in your example (`datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 10, 9, 1`) is a general representation of the `datetime.datetime` object and does not tell you anything about having or not having the information about milliseconds. See @dail45 answer to get the information about milliseconds, and if it helps you, accept their answer as the correct one.

Comment: Please include screenshot in body of question instead of a link.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can use `datetime.microseconds()`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime.strptime("2010-01-01 10:09:01.020", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
print(a.microsecond)  # >> 20000
print(a.microsecond//1000)  # >> 20
```

And you can add `if` blocks or something that you need.

This is inside of value "a":

[image: screenshot]